# How to use Applescript to turn off Apple TV in iTunes?

Tags: macos, itunes, applescript, automator, ui

In Automator, I would need an Applescript who turn off Apple TV sound.

See this picture. I need the "Apple TV salon PT" checkbox unchecked.

[image]

Comment: AskDifferent is not a service to do this for you. Please edit your question with what research you have already done, what you have found online or what you have done yourself. I would imagine a lot of what you want is AppleScript-101. EG extremely basic.

Answer (score 4):

This Applescript does the job very well!

```
tell application "iTunes" to get name of AirPlay devices
tell application "iTunes" to set selected of AirPlay device "Apple TV salon PT" to false
```